# C++ : how to get a long value from json and convert it to time_point

Tags: c++, json, date, parsing, long-integer

I'm quite new to c++ so thera are a bunch of questions I've got but for now this one drives my crazy:

I've ot a json response and want to parse one object as long (because it's a timestamp). After that I want tp parse that long to a time_point object via

```
chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(...);
```

So this is what I got for now:

```
auto last_change_date_long = (long long)json_troubleticket["lastChangeDate"].int_value();
time_t last_change_date_raw = time_t(last_change_date_long);
auto last_change_date = chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(last_change_date_raw);
```

It compiles, but if i run this (while I know the value for **lastChangeDate** is `1480702672000`) it's result is 
`2147483647000` ...

Does anyone have a suggestion what went wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing the int_value() function truncates the value since it's converting to an integer.

Comment: Have you noticed that 2147483647 is 0x7FFFFFFF (INT_MAX)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
auto i = 1480702672000;
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp{std::chrono::milliseconds{i}};
```

Note that the above is not *guaranteed* to work by the standard because the epoch of `system_clock` is unspecified.  However all implementations are currently using [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), and I have an informal agreement with the implementors that they will not deviate from this while I try to standardize this existing practice.

The reason you're seeing the behavior you have is that your json is counting milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, but `time_t` typically counts seconds (though that is also not specified by the standard).  So at the point where you create `last_change_date_raw` from `last_change_date_long`, you're implicitly converting milliseconds to seconds.  This would result in a date midway through the year 48891.  The implementation of `from_time_t` is likely freaking out about that (overflowing).

Fwiw, this particular time point represents:

```
2016-12-02 18:17:52.000 UTC
```

Comment: the json response changed, so I've got no chance to test this right now.

Comment: @grumpyshoe:  I'd be happy to post further UTC-formated time points based on your current inputs.  Lag time may be hours.  I'll do the best I can.